# Resizing window results in stretching texture

Tags: java, opengl, glsl, shader, lwjgl

Hello since I'm new to VAOs and shaders,

I tried to initially start with a test project.
[The complete code is in the LWJGL wiki and is the same as my code.](http://wiki.lwjgl.org/wiki/The_Quad_textured.html)

My problem is the original window with its original size looks like this: [image]

But after resizing the window it looks like this:
[image]

But it should look like this:
[image]

So the texture should not change its size or aspect ratio.

What should I do?

Comment: Have you started using perspective matrices yet? OpenGL normalized coordinates are [-1, 1] on every axis, changing the window size only changes the OpenGL viewport not the OpenGL normalized device coordinates. https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Transformations

Comment: @Xamser7 Is there no easier way to do this?

Comment: I mean, you just haven't learned it yet I suppose. Don't worry about it for now because this how OpenGL works. Once you learn about perspective and transformation matrices you will be able to achieve this more easily.